# Reading a large tsv file with different column through pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata, data-analysis

I have a big tsv file of around 140 million rows. However, when I try to read the file through different codes I am suffering from different errors.

- `pd.read_csv('abc.tsv',delimiter='\t',encoding='utf-8')` 
  It only reads
  around 35988840 rows without any error or warning
- `np.genfromtxt("abc.tsv", names=True, delimiter="\t", invalid_raise = False)` -
  It read the 35988840  rows with following message.

  > **main**:1: ConversionWarning: Some errors were detected !  Line#35988840 (got 3 columns instead of 8)
- `np.genfromtxt("abc.tsv", names=True, delimiter="\t")`
- `np.genfromtxt("abc.tsv", names=True, delimiter="\t", skip_header=1)`
- `np.genfromtxt("abc.tsv", names=True, delimiter="\t", invalid_raise = False)`

Same error in the last three about number of columns being different. 
How do we go about it? Please help

Comment: Hi Rajan, please check in your file at line 35988840 if there are actually 8 columns or if there are only 3. This message probably indicates that there are only 2 delimiters at that line, which makes only 3 columns instead of 8.

Comment: you can use this:
`df = pd.read_csv('abc.tsv',delimiter='\t',encoding='utf-8', skiprows=35988839, nrows=1)` to inspect the file at that specific row